# Can't see logo in Google Chrome but can in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

Title explains all, I can't see what the issue is personally, I suspected may an issue with the CSS but it looks just fine in IE and Firefox, I don't see why chrome is struggling?

I have tried adding

```
#logo img
{
width: 50%;
float:left;
}
```

To try to directly style the image, still no luck

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"> 
<div id ="logo">
<img src="Media/Images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="75%" height="142px;" />
</div>

<div id="icons">
    <img src="Media/Images/EnvelopeIcon.png" alt="Envelope Icon" height="25" width="30">
    <p>M015734a@student.staffs.ac.uk</p>
    <div class="clear">     
    </div>
    <img src="Media/Images/PhoneIcon.png" alt="Envelope Icon" height="25" width="30" />
    <p> 07904921417</p>
    <div class="clear">     
    </div>
    <img src="Media/Images/HouseIcon.png" alt="Envelope Icon" height="25" width="30">
        <p>Stafford, UK</p>
    <div class="clear">     
    </div>              
<div class="clear">     
</div>
</div>
</div>

<nav>
<div id ="NavBG">
safsafnsakn
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>

#logo
{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;

}

#logo img
{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a workaround to this issue. You can try to use `<object>` instead of `<img>`

```
<object height="100%" width="100%" data="Media/Images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
```

Please also refer to the following links for more details.

http://e.metaclarity.org/52/cross-browser-svg-issues/
http://henkelmann.eu/2010/12/16/display_svg_image_same_size_in_decent_browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can't just append CSS to the end of the file. It has to either be inline, included as an external file, or placed inside `style` tags in the head.

Try moving the CSS into the head, like so:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
<title>Welcome!</title>
<style>
#logo
{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;

}

#logo img
{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
```

If you cannot solve the issue of the logo not appearing in Chrome, please recreate your file in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), complete with images and your external css.css file, and post a link here.

Comment: Sorry for the complication, i have taken the CSS scripts from my external stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

Please Use different type of image. Check The link

```
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119693
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably in the `img` tag:

```
<img src="Media/Images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="75%" height="142px;" />
```

You can't specify units using the "height" or "width" attributes - I would just remove them entirely and style the image using CSS.

Comment: Have just tried removing height and width from inline, its relying solely on the css elements for styling now. 
Logo still isn't appearing :(

Comment: Have just found the issue, it seems that svg's don't work well within img tags, so i've embedded it with

<embed src="Media/Images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />

Answer (score 0):

Change your code  from

```
link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"
```

to

```
link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.png"
```

Also rename image to .png. As Chrome doesn't pick the ico icons for sometimes.
It works for me.